# Callback delegates being collected?

Tags: c#, delegates, garbage-collection, fmod

Been messing around with FMOD for C# game development and I've hit a snag early on that I can't seem to get around. I want to do some branching audio stuff and sync some gameplay action to beats and such, so I've tried adding syncpoints to my music tracks. Here's code:

```
public class Music
{
    private Sound music;
    private Channel channel;
    private IntPtr syncPtr;

    public string File { get; private set; }  

    public Music(string file)
    {
        File = file;
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        music = new Sound();
        Audio.System.createSound(File, MODE.HARDWARE, ref music);
    }

    public void Unload()
    {
        music.release();
    }

    public virtual void Play()
    {
        Audio.System.playSound(channel == null ? CHANNELINDEX.FREE : CHANNELINDEX.REUSE, music, false, ref channel);
        music.addSyncPoint(500, TIMEUNIT.MS, "wooo", ref syncPtr);
        channel.setCallback(channelCallback);
    }

    private RESULT channelCallback(IntPtr channelraw, CHANNEL_CALLBACKTYPE type, IntPtr commanddata1, IntPtr commanddata2)
    {
        if (type == CHANNEL_CALLBACKTYPE.SYNCPOINT)
            Console.WriteLine("sync!");

        return RESULT.OK;
    }
}
```

And then...

```
m = new Music(MUS_TUTORIAL);  //m is static
m.Load();
m.Play();
```

The song loads and plays fine... until it hits that 500ms syncpoint I added. At this point, VC# spits out the following error from within FMOD.EventSystem.update():

> A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type
>   'Game!FMOD.CHANNEL_CALLBACK::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and
>   data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the
>   managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.

So somehow FMOD is losing track of the delegate I passed it. The Music instance that holds the delegate has not been garbage collected - I'm storing it in a static variable for now - but I've tried with a static method too to no avail. If I disable the CallbackOnCollectedDelegate MDA the error becomes a null reference exception, so the MDA isn't mistaken. I assume I must just not fully understand what FMOD is doing here.

Are any C# + FMOD gurus able to see my mistake?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to put things like "C# - FMOD - " into your titles. The tags accomplish the same thing, without making your title ugly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
    channel.setCallback(channelCallback);
```

That's the problem statement.  FMod is unmanaged code.  You are creating a delegate object here and passing it to the unmanaged code.  Problem is, the garbage collector cannot track references held by native code.  The next garbage collection will find *no* references to the object and collect it.  Kaboom when the native code makes the callback.

You need to keep a reference yourself so this won't happen:

```
public class Music
{
    private SomeDelegateType callback
    //...
    public Music(string file)
    {
        File = file;
        callback = new SomeDelegateType(channelCallback);
    }

    public virtual void Play()
    {
        Audio.System.playSound(channel == null ? CHANNELINDEX.FREE : CHANNELINDEX.REUSE, music, false, ref channel);
        music.addSyncPoint(500, TIMEUNIT.MS, "wooo", ref syncPtr);
        channel.setCallback(callback);
    }
```

You need to find the actual delegate type from the FMod wrapper code, I merely guessed at "SomeDelegateType".

Comment: Ahh okay thanks, it was a misunderstanding of how delegates work on my part then.

Comment: A delegate is an object in it's own right. This is sometimes hidden by the shortcut syntax supported since C# 2.0 where the compiler does the conversion on your behalf. In your case the code `channel.setCallback(channelCallback);` is converted by the compiler into `channel.setCallback(new SomeDelegateType(channelCallback));`.

Comment: My compliments on the question btw, you made it easy to help you.  Perfect description of the problem, posting *exactly* the right code. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem between VB.NET and a custom C++ DLL.  Fixed thanks to @Hans.  I owe this site many times over for all the problems it's got me through.  Adding my problem+solution in hopes it helps others seeing the same solution in a different context.

Declared this (in a module)

```
Public Delegate Sub CB_FUNC(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)
Public Declare Sub vidProc_cb_MouseClick Lib "C:\Users\.....\vidProc\product\vidProc.dll" (ByVal addr_update As CB_FUNC)
```

### Originally:

Had a simple call in a button_click sub:

```
vidProc_cb_MouseClick(AddressOf updateXY)
```

I would get the 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' error.  Not immediately, but after interacting with other objects on the form, then trying to invoke the callback (which in my case was a mouse click in an OpenCV window).

### Fixed by:

1) Declaring (in the Form Class, Declarations)

```
Private addr_update As CB_FUNC
```

2) Defining addr_update on Form Load

```
addr_update = New CB_FUNC(AddressOf updateXY)
```

3) Calling my 'set callback' function with the new pointer (in the button_click sub)

```
vidProc_cb_MouseClick(addr_update)
```

I think I understood @Hans and implemented it correctly (I can't reproduce the error).  Hope this helps someone.